# Postgres: n:m intermediate table with type

Tags: postgresql, foreign-keys, many-to-many

I have a table called "Tag" which consists of an Id, Name and Description column.

Now lets say I have the tables Character (C), Movie (M), Series (S) etc..
And I want to be able to tag entries in C, M, S with multiple tags and one tag may be used for multiple entries.
So I could realize it like this:

```
T -> TC <- C  
T -> TM <- M  
T -> TS <- S
```

Where TC, TM, TS are the intermediate tables.
I was wondering if I could combine TC, TM, TS into one table with a type column added and still use foreign keys.
As of yet I haven't found a way to do it.
Or is this something I shouldn't be doing?

Comment: You can't combine that tables into single table and still use foreign keys. If you combine them, you'll have to maintain referential integrity in your application. But such an approach is appropriate, at least I saw some rather sophisticated systems, that have such a combined n:m tables.

Comment: @Tometzky For this particular problem, there was no real reason. Just the next step of a train of thought: Need many intermediate tables -> they look similar -> can I combine them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the comments above suggested you can't combine multiple table into a single one. If you want to have a single view of the "tag relationships" you can pull the needed information into a [View](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createview.html). This way, you only need to write a longer query once and are able to use like a single table. Keep in mind that you can't insert data into a view (there are possibilities to do so, but they are a little advanced)